# How to split strings in an array into two new arrays

Tags: python, string, list

I would like to be able to make an array like `list1 = ['a/b','c/d','e/f']` into `list2= ['a','c','e']` and `list3 = ['b','d','f']`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well it's quite straight forward. Where do you have an issue with your code?

Comment: I had tried the logic that pygri used before but only the b[0] version, I was not sure how to get the information after the '/'.

Comment: that's cool, for the future don't be afraid to post what you tried and where you got stuck, it helps getting good answers

Answer (score 5):

I would do it this way:

```
list1 = ['a/b','c/d','e/f']

list2, list3 = map(list, zip(*(x.split('/') for x in list1)))
print(list2, list3)
# ['a', 'c', 'e'] ['b', 'd', 'f']
```

---

What you do is to create a generator that yields a tuple consisting of the strings left and right of the `/` char, respectively. Then use `zip()` to unfold these into the tuples consisting of the first and second elements, respectively. Finally, `map()` is used to convert the `tuple`s returned by `zip()` into `list`s.

Answer (score 3):

```
[b[0] for b in [a.split('/') for a in list1]]
['a', 'c', 'e']

[b[1] for b in [a.split('/') for a in list1]]
['b', 'd', 'f']
```

Comment: Thank you I just needed to save those lines to new arrays to use them.

Comment: @Conasty: do you understand why this work? if not it is a good exercise to do it step by step to get a feeling what is happening here - what does the split do, and how we fill in the values in the result

Answer (score 1):

In one line :

```
list1 = ['a/b','c/d','e/f']
list2, list3 = [x.split('/')[0] for x in list1], [x.split('/')[1] for x in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 l2 = []
 l3 = []
 l1 = ['a/b','c/d','e/f']
 for item in l1:
        item1, item2 = item.split("/")
        l2.append(item1)
        l3.append(item2)
```